# How to draw a line on a highcharts graph from an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, highcharts

I have in my html page a highcharts graph that I want to update dynamically. I have some input boxes that once they get updated by the user, trigger an AJAX post request. The request does some calculations and I want the output to be used to re-draw the line of my chart's second serie . That line represents a simple y = x function, the 'x' variable being calculated during the AJAX call.

Here is my html/JS code for the chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                animation: Highcharts.svg,
                marginRight: 10,
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Strategy Payoff'
            },
            xAxis: {
                //type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },

            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'PnL',
                data: (function () {
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;
                    var V = document.getElementById('V').value;
                    var Q = document.getElementById('Q').value;
                    var S = document.getElementById('S').value;
                    var K = document.getElementById('K').value;
                    var Type = document.getElementById('Type').value;

                    if (Type == 'Call') {
                      direction = 1;
                    } else {
                      direction = -1;
                    }

                    if (S >= 5000) {
                      stepSize = 500;
                    } else if (S >= 500) {
                      stepSize = 50;
                    } else {
                      stepSize = 1;
                    }

                    for (i = 0; i <= S * 2; i+=stepSize) { // i+=stepSize
                        data.push({
                            x: i,
                            y: Math.max(-V * Q, -V * Q + Q * direction * (i-K))
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            }, {
                name: 'Current Option Strategy PnL',
                data: (function pnl(value=10) {
                      var data2 = [],
                          time2 = (new Date()).getTime(),
                          i;
                      var S = document.getElementById('S').value;

                      if (S >= 5000) {
                      stepSize = 500;
                      } else if (S >= 500) {
                      stepSize = 50;
                      } else {
                      stepSize = 1;
                      }

                      for (i = 0; i <= S * 2; i+=stepSize) {
                        data2.push({
                            x: i,
                            y: value
                        });
                      }

                    return data2;
                })()
            }]
        });
    });

});

  </script>
```

Here are the input boxes that trigger the AJAX request when updated by the user:

```
 <div class="chart" id="container"></div>

 <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <span>Option 1 Imp. Vol.</span>
    <input class="toChange" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" type="range" value="{{Sigma}}" min="0.1" max="150" lang="en_EN" step="0.1" oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value" />
    <input class="toChange" id="amount" type="number" value="{{Sigma}}" min="0.1" max="150" lang="en_EN" step="0.1"oninput="rangeInput.value=amount.value" />
  </div>
```

Finally, here is the AJAX request itself:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function inputChange () {
        var Sigma = document.getElementById("rangeInput").value;
        var Type = document.getElementById('Type').value;
        var S = document.getElementById('S').value;
        var K = document.getElementById('K').value;
        var t = document.getElementById('t').value;
        var r = document.getElementById('r').value;
        var V = document.getElementById('V').value;
        var Q = document.getElementById('Q').value;
        $.ajax({
                url: '/optionstrategies/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                  'Type': Type,
                  'S': S,
                  'K': K,
                  'r': r,
                  't': t,
                  'Sigma': Sigma,
                },
                success: function(optionVal) {
                alert((optionVal - V) * Q);
                document.getElementById("oPrice").innerHTML = optionVal;
                document.getElementById("PnL").innerHTML = (optionVal - V) * Q;
                // pnl(12);
                }
        }); 
    }

    $(".toChange").change(inputChange); 
 </script>
```

The AJAX call works well as the alert shows the expected value. I now need to use that value to update my chart. So for instance, if the value is equal to 12, I need the second serie of my chart to draw a line representing the y = 12 function.
I've named the function dealing with my second serie 'pnl' as you can see. I've been trying to call that function in the 'success' part of my AJAX request by writing something like 'pnl(12);', but it didn't do anything. Could anybody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **series.update** feature inside the success call and set the new data on it. Please check the available demos under below link.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

If this clue wouldn't help, please reproduce a simplified version of your code on some online editor which I could work on.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!